# Swift: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, jsonencoder

I have a git repository of an app that has been working properly and is available on iTunes. I recently wanted to add some updates to it and imported the project into xCode 10. When I tried to build the solution, I get an error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

I have tried to update all the pods that are being used.

Here is the code with the error

```
static func toJSON<T>(_ data: [T]) -> NSArray {
    let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)
    let jsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoded,
                                                       options: []) as! NSArray
    return jsonObject
}
```

and the error seems to appear on this line

```
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)
```

I am very new to Swift and only inherited this project so I am unsure as to what my approach should be in resolving this issue. I've looked through other questions but could not see a solution that would work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic parameter `T` must be constrained to `Encodable` and please use *swiftier* code and `throw` potential errors

```
static func toJSON<T : Encodable>(_ data: [T]) throws -> [Any] {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(data)
    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoded) as! [Any]
}
```

Comment: I tried the suggested approach and the original error is gone, now I am getting the following: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled. Where should I add the catch?

Comment: You have to call the method with `try toJSON...` wrapped in a `try - catch` block.